# pyMySQL: How to check if connection is already opened or close

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am getting the error `InterfaceError (0, '')`. Is there way in `Pymysql` library I can check whether connection or cursor is closed. For cursor I am already using context manager like that:

```
with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
  ....
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use Connection.open attribute.

The Connection.open field will be 1 if the connection is open and 0 otherwise. So you can say

```
if conn.open:
    # do something
```

> The conn.open attribute will tell you whether the connection has been
>   explicitly closed or whether a remote close has been detected.
>   However, it's always possible that you will try to issue a query and
>   suddenly the connection is found to have given out - there is no way
>   to detect this ahead of time (indeed, it might happen during the
>   process of issuing the query), so the only truly safe thing is to wrap
>   your calls in a try/except block

Comment: Is it not `MySQLDb` specific? Could not find any such thing in `pymysql` lib.

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L740).

Comment: As @phd mentioned. Connection is having open property in pymysql

Comment: the connection.open object in pymsql package will give out the value True or False, so basically a Boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Use conn.connection in if statement.

```
import pymysql

def conn():
    mydb=pymysql.Connect('localhost','root','password','demo_db',autocommit=True)
    return mydb.cursor()

def db_exe(query,c):
    try:
        if c.connection:
            print("connection exists")
            c.execute(query)
            return c.fetchall()
        else:
            print("trying to reconnect")
            c=conn()
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

dbc=conn()
print(db_exe("select * from users",dbc))
```

Answer (score 3):

I initially went with the solution from AKHIL MATHEW to call conn.open but later during testing found that sometimes conn.open was returning positive results even though the connection was lost. To be certain, I found I could call [conn.ping()](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/9f1b8569032ec7eaff36fe9ef5e40f82c47260b2/pymysql/connections.py#L520) which actually tests the connection. The function also accepts an optional parameter (reconnect=True) which will cause it to automatically reconnect if the ping fails.

Of course there is a cost to this - as implied by the name, ping actually goes out to the server and tests the connection. You don't want to do this before every query, but in my case I have an AWS lambda spinning up on warm start and trying to reuse the connection, so I think I can justify testing my connection once on each warm start and reconnecting if it's been lost.

Comment: I have found ping reconnect true to be the most rock solid way of dealing with this, particularly when trying to have a global connection in a lambda as noted. Also use it in CLI batch code that has a lot of time between queries.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, because I want to still run the query even if the connection goes down:

```
def reconnect():
    mydb=pymysql.Connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='password',database='demo_db',ssl={"fake_flag_to_enable_tls":True},autocommit=True)
    return mydb.cursor()


try:
    if (c.connection.open != True):
        c=reconnect() # reconnect
    if c.connection.open:
        c.execute(query)
        return c.fetchall()
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the try and catch might do the trick instead of checking cursor only.

```
try:
   c = db_connection.cursor()
except OperationalError:
   connected = False
else:
   connected = True
   #code here
```